# firewall NAT failed while working on nearby equipment; bad cable, both nets up, but packets not passed; troubleshooting advice?

Tags: iptables, nat, firewalld

We're FINALLY replacing some older equipment and as a part of that work I pulled two very deep drawers holding equipment farther out than they'd been moved in many years. One of those drawers has a firewall on it, the other has a switch to which the firewall was connected, and **one of the CAT-V cables was pulled to its limit without my noticing, but the firewall was left running - "it wasn't touched."**

"The problem" was, namely, that the internal network was (is) no longer able to get to the wilds of the internet. All the machines of the internal network seemed fine but unable to get to the firewall machine. Yet, the firewall remained up and was able to reach the internet though it couldn't see systems on the internal net.

Basic troubleshooting - just looking - led to discovering the cable that was still at its limit. A longer cable was sourced that could be routed properly  and never reach its limit, and once it was installed, **now the internal systems all see the firewall once more and the firewall sees both the outside world and the internal net, yet it isn't passing packets properly, even though no changes were made other than the cable.**

**It's supposed to be passing internal network connections through to the outside using NAT** and then serving httpd internally and externally. (I had thought it was also receiving inbound email from the internet and passing it to a particular internal system via port-forwarding, but it turns out **email isn't working because the email server confirms inbound via DNS and those lookups aren't being passed through properly.**) The system is talking inbound and outbound just fine, but it's not routing through (with or without NAT). ... Of course, as luck would have it, this firewall is supposed to be replaced early next week as its new equipment is due in on Monday.

This firewall is Linux 3.14.27-100.fc19.x86_64 and dates from 2014 - like I said, it's old, and this version's network software never really worked right anyway, but it was good enough to leave in service. (The same system has been serving other needs too, like web services).

I'm pretty sure it has kernel-based IP Tables as the core workhorse with a buggy firewalld helping to confuse things. It's been too many years since I messed with this but I seem to recall that someone had advised mucking with the "save on restart" feature as I played with it to be able to capture the configuration once it was working properly, and I may have done that. But you can inadvertently change the rules if you do it wrong, so, I'm trying to be cautious. The file that controls that is /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config and it hasn't been edited since the system was first configured. Its neighbor, the file 'firewalld', has no arguments defined and also hasn't been edited since then.

As a first step:

```
systemctl status firewalld.service
```

This showed it was up and has `"ERROR: ZONE_CONFLICT"`, repeated twice, but with a timestamp from the last system restart, long predating this failure.

The config for the firewall is in /etc/firewalld/zones. There are three defined, external, internal and public. The files haven't changed, and their contents look reasonable.

It's worth mentioning that the system has a problem booting and I'm loathe to just reboot it since it may not come back up! Right now at least it's serving web pages. ...It'll be replaced next week some time but I'd rather not have all those web sites (maybe 60?) down for several days if I can avoid it.

I cycled firewalld with systemctl, but there was no change. ... Can IP Tables be cycled, too? As its part of the kernel, I didn't think so, but maybe?

Ideas?

**Update:** At some point I figured out that the web pages were not, in fact, being served, so at that point it's the same as if the system was simply down completely. I decided it was worth trying a reboot. The system hung twice during reboot but eventually I got it to boot, and, yes, you knew it, the reboot cured the problem. The system is now both passing packets via NAT and is serving those web pages. (I'm now anxiously awaiting UPS to deliver the new hardware!)

**That said** ... I have this strong sense that it should have been fixable without the reboot. And I'd love to hear any ideas about that.

Comment: Maybe restarting some services like firewalld would've helped?

Comment: @SirMuffington Thanks for the thought, but I did try it, to no avail. ... I suppose I'm correct that there is no way to cycle IP Tables itself since it's in the kernel?